# Calculate an ellipse from 3-4 points that is parallel to the X and Y axes

Tags: conic-sections

I'm working on a simple graphics tool that currently draws an ellipse using a bounding rectangle. This is nice and simple, as you just drag the two corners of the rectangle to where you want it.

I have been requested to generate an ellipse using 3-4 points that exist along the ellipse perimeter. This way you can plot 3 or 4 points along the edge of a pre-existing ellipse and have the tool match it.

The constraints are that the ellipse major & minor axes are parallel to the X and Y axes, no rotation. Is this possible?

From what I can understand so far is that from only 3 points, I can only reliably create a circle, but would 4 points be enough to calculate the Major Axis, Minor Axis, and Center of an ellipse?

**Update: Clarification**
None of the points are expected to reside on either Major or Minor axis, and the center is expected to never be zero.

**Update 2: Must have 4 points**
Based on the discussion here: [How many points are needed to uniquely define an ellipse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063610/how-many-points-are-needed-to-uniquely-define-an-ellipse), 4 points will define an infinite number of ellipses. So it looks like I would need to have a minimum of 5 points.

Comment: I've seen this equation, but my understanding is that it expects one of the points to be on either the Major or Minor axis so you can solve for a or b. None of the points are expected to be on an axis, and the center is expected to never be (0,0). Can this equation be solved for that?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where you see the 4 free terms. I only see 2 sets of XY values and then an AB pair.

Comment: If you have the four points, say, $(x,y)=(2,5),(5,6),(6,2),(3,2),$ then this gives the four equations in four variables `solve([(2-x0)^2/a^2+(5-y0)^2/b^2-1,(5-x0)^2/a^2+(6-y0)^2/b^2-1,(6-x0)^2/a^2+(2-y0)^2/b^2-1,(3-x0)^2/a^2+(2-y0)^2/b^2-1],[a,b,x0,y0]);` which gives the solution $a^2=\frac{2275}{22}, b^2=\frac{2275}{264}, x_0=\frac92, y_0=\frac{85}{22}.$

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224627/409) gives a determinant that generates the equation of a conic from five points (as part of a discussion of when the fifth point yields an ellipse). To glean geometric properties from the equation, you could look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/801572/409), which gives various formulas (although not always in the clearest manner).

Comment: If the four points are corners of a rectangle that is parallel to the two axes, there is not a unique solution.

Comment: If all your points lie on a line, you don't get an ellipse no matter how many points you specify. So without any generality assumptions you won't get a number of "needed" points. An axes-aligned ellipse "needs" four general points, where general means no three on a line; no four make a axes-aligned rectangle; no one point in the convex hull of the other three (in this case the solution wants to be a axes-aligned hyperbola). A not necessarily axes-aligned (general) conic needs five general points, where general points means "no three of the points on a line". Hyperbolas and parabolas may occur.