# circumcircle of point of contact of tangent to a circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

Tangents drawn from the point $P(1, 8)$ to the circle
 $x^2 + y^2 - 6x - 4y - 11 = 0$  touch the circle at the points A and B. Will the circumcircle of triangle $PAB$ pass through $(3,2)$ or the center of the first circle?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the construction of the points of tangency using straight-edge and compass. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223566).  A circle is drawn so that $(1,8)$ and $(3,2)$ are at opposite ends of one of its diameters.

[image]