# Construct a tangent line through a given point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a **random** point $A$ **outside the circle**, and a circle centered at $C$, how do I construct a line that is tangent to the circle $C$ passing through $A$, using **only Euclid's elementary constructions**?

Comment: It is impossible if the point is inside the circle. Otherwise it is trivial if the center of the circle is known.

Comment: No, I wasn't so clear. The point is outside the circle.

Comment: You can do that also without knowing the point $C$. You can even to that without a compass, with a straight egde alone. :)

Comment: How do you propose to do that?

Comment: @JohnGlenn Please see a description at [A tangent to a circle with a straight edge](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2674786/152299).

Comment: Very clever! @CiaPan

Comment: I have just found a similar question at [Construct tangent to a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223566/152299), asked in October '12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a circle with diameter $CA$. Its intersection with the original circle will give the tangent points.

Comment: Very clever. Thales' theorem makes it true.